# Handling response errors/http status through fetch promises

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch-api, catch-block

This is kind of a two part question, the first being specific to my personal circumstance and the second being an overall understanding of how things function.

I am performing a password reset for my application. The email gets sent along with a `jwt` attached to the URL. After the user clicks the URL they are taken to the reset password page that fires of an action with the `jwt` through `componentWillMount` function. This action then fires off the `fetch`:

```
static verifyResetPasswordToken(token) {
  const obj = JSON.stringify(token);
  return fetch('/api/auth/verifyResetPasswordToken', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: obj
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('THEN');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('CATCH');
    });
}
```

On the API I'm handling this by taking the token passed in the body and checking if it has expired or not:

```
export function verifyResetPasswordToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = jwt.decode(req.body.token);
  if (token.exp > Date.now() / 1000) {
    res.status(200).json();
  } else {
    res.status(401).json();
  }
}
```

**NOTE** I understand this is not a secure way to check the validity of a token. I just need to figure out if it is expired or not.

Here is where the confusion lies. When the `401` status gets returned, my promise is rejected. It is my understanding that `fetch` does not handle errors this way. That the only thing `fetch` catches is `network connectivity` and that I should still hit my `then()` block even with 400 & 500 http status errors. Any idea as to why my promise is getting rejected with a `401` status? Why am I landing in the `catch` block? How do I avoid this from happening? How do I handle different status that I want to respond with on my server?

My second question revolves around all of this. What is the best practice for handling server errors when working with `fetch` and maybe specifically `React` `Redux`? This is my first time using `fetch` and any light that can be shed to understanding how I should handle server side errors would be greatly appreciated.

```
static verifyResetPasswordToken(token) {
  const obj = JSON.stringify(token);
  return fetch('/api/auth/verifyResetPasswordToken', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: obj
  })
    .then(res => {
      if(res.ok) {
        console.log('THEN');
      } else {
        console.log('ELSE');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('CATCH');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[As per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful), and as you already note, the `fetch()` API only rejects a promise when a “network error is encountered, although this usually means permissions issues or similar.”

However `fetch` provides an ok flag that indicates whether an HTTP response’s status code is in the successful range or not.

```
static verifyResetPasswordToken(token) {
  const obj = JSON.stringify(token);
  return fetch('/api/auth/verifyResetPasswordToken', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: obj
  }).then(res => {
     if (!res.ok) {
       throw Error(res.statusText);
     }
     return res;
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('THEN');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('CATCH');
    });
}
```

Comment: I was using the `res.ok` function (see example above). Yet my promise still got rejected. It appears that the difference is you have thrown in a callback to your callback. Is this normally how you need to handle responses? Any idea as to why the new example above doesn't work? thanks for your time Pual.

Comment: if the error will not be rejected by the `fetch` api then you need to reject it yourself by throwing an error. This is probably a shortcoming with the API but this is the suggested workaround. So as noted above as the fetch() API only rejects a promise when a network error is encountered you need to throw the error yourself if it falls outside this category. You could possibly look at using a library that will prob make it easier to handle these such as axios which was at least previously, the library react recommended using for ajax requests - https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Comment: What is interesting is I never hit the `then` block. Even if I throw an error myself. I never hit it. Which leads me to believe that the `fetch` API is handling the `401` status as an error. =/

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed, but I wasn't actually testing this with an expired token. Now that I am using the example you have provided(copy pasted), it is still rejecting the promise and I'm landing in the `catch`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nappstir no need to be embarrassed :-) I thought you wanted to land in the `catch` block.

Comment: So now knowing that I am trying to avoid the `catch` block, any ideas as to why responding with a `401` would reject the promise?

Comment: @Nappstir when using your code, and not using the code I provided? Also, are you having any CORS issues? Also, this could be worth a read https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/201

Comment: The promise still gets rejected with the code that you provided. Never hit the `then` block. It will go straight to rejecting the promise. The error the server returns is as follows: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`. This should be CORS related I dont think. I have looked into it and it doesn't seem to be the problem. I was reading through that exact link making sure that CORS wasn't an issue.